# Add css class in next page after follow link (asp.net-mvc razor)

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the drop-down menu on jQuery. I need activate menu item and submenu item in next page after follow link.
Before:

```
<div class="menu__item">Menu Item 1</div>
<div class="menu__item__submenu">
     @Html.ActionLink("Submenu item 1", ..., new { @class = "submenu__item" })
```

After:

```
<div class="menu__item menu__item-active">Menu Item 1</div>
<div class="menu__item__submenu submenu-active-js">
     @Html.ActionLink("Submenu item 1", ..., new { @class = "submenu__item submenu__item-active" })
```

How i can make it?

Comment: for this you need to make code with condition statement "If...Else". also identify using URL detect code for identifying sub page or other pages. if page url true then put code with active class otherwise put without class.

Comment: I thought the same with switch/case. Can you tell me about the methods for changing class?

Comment: Yep, Also use swith/case. for methods check answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just example not perfect code. you need to customization as per your code.

like:

```
switch (window.location.pathname) {
    case '/technology':
        $('#main').addClass('tech')
    case '/something':
    case '/somestuff':
        $('#main').addClass('some')
}
```

Comment: than you very much

Answer (score 0):

I was make it like this:
In the controller we add to the methods that are called from the submenu

```
public ActionResult CertInstall()
    {
        ViewData["MenuItemActive"] = "menu__item-active";
        ViewData["SubMenuActive"] = "menu__item__submenu-active";
        ViewData["CertInstal_SubMenuActive"] = "submenu__item-active";
        return View(ViewData);
    }
```

in the menu view:

```html
<menu class="menu-wrap">
    @Html.ActionLink("Main", "Index", "Home", null, new {@class = "menu__item"})
    <div class="menu__item @ViewData["MenuItemActive"]">
        Menu Item 1
    </div>
    <div class="menu__item__submenu @ViewData["SubMenuActive"]">
        @Html.ActionLink("Certificate Order", "CertOrder", "Home", null, new { @class = "submenu__item " + @ViewData["CertOrder_SubMenuActive"] })
        @Html.ActionLink("Certificate Install", "CertInstall", "Home", null, new { @class = "submenu__item " + @ViewData["CertInstal_SubMenuActive"] })
     </div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Contacts", "Contacts", "Home", null, new { @class = "menu__item" })
</menu>
```

PS. Yes this is a bad code, but I don't know how to do it better